# This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled - PYTHON

Tags: javascript, python, cookies

I have a relatively small crawler, which reads website with threading, via urllib2. Now I have the issue that I have to read thousends of webpages, with upwards ID's. It works fine for some websites, but other websites give me errors like "This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled". Does anyone know how to fix this in the most easy way? And not slows down my crawler.....

Thanks...

Comment: Have you considered writing your own Javascript interpreter? But seriously, crawlers usually don't execute javascript, which is why you get that error.

Comment: I'm not that experienced yet unfortunately. I'm just able to write some simple Python code. Just hoping this was easy to fix...

Comment: It is not easy to fix.

Comment: Python won't execute JS code for you. You could have a look at the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey/0.0.10 project, a python bining to the spidermonkey JS engine.